# Product Recommendation based on purchase history

Tags: machine-learning

I am dealing with problem where i have to increase the sales by product recommendation.I only have customer data and product that they have purchased.No ratings,reviews or feedback is present.What approach fit best for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you don't have ratings or reviews, you can use the customer purchases to help creating your model and selecting the most appropriate one. If the customer has bought the product, you can suppose he has liked it. If he hasn't, we can suppose he has disliked it. This is an approach which is mainly used by e-shops.

You can find more on recommendation system selection and validation below. It is discussed how to choose the best recommender with both offline and online approaches.

https://medium.com/recombee-blog/evaluating-recommender-systems-choosing-the-best-one-for-your-business-c688ab781a35